# How long should a swipe action be to open a sidebar?

Tags: user-behavior, sidebar, gestures, swipe

How long/quick should a left or right movement be in order to indicate it's a swipe rather than user scrolling the page?

I was thinking, *if user isn't scrolling in the y axis and performed* **touch start**, **touch move** and **touch end** actions (in that order) and *user moved more than 3% of the screen's width*, check if: *those actions happened **quicker** than 100ms, in which case, trigger swipe*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Do Not Use a Swipe Action*** if what you are building is a webpage.

If it's a mobile app, let the system i.e Android or iOS etc. handle the drawer or sidebar speed.

But if its a mobile view for a website, then avoid the swipe. Your best bet for users to view the menu is a "Click", not a "Swipe". Make it as clear as possible, that this a menu button.

However if you really still wanna implement the drawer/slide for the sidebar menu. It's been estimated that the Android Drawer, sliding time is *200-300ms*

Comment: My side menu has both actions, click and swipe. Click is the main one, but I have swipe as well, for users to have a quicker way to open it if they want. As for webapp vs native, I think you’re right about that, use the system default, what the user expects for native apps. My use case was specifically webapps though I didn’t mention that in my question

Comment: @ElliotSchep alright I have edited the answer. To cover for the estimated time for sliding.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great tutorial about creating a touch menu by Rita Dias.
https://www.outsystems.com/blog/mobile-touch-gestures.html

I hope this will help you

Comment: That’s a really good informative article; thank you. I would like to see some more to your answer though, as I don’t think providing a link to an article can be properly called an answer. Regardless, here’s an upvote (well, not really, I’ve got less than 15rep here)

Comment: You are right, i'm unfortunately at work right now :D but tried to help you anyway